# dialogRef.close() is not a function opening from one component and closing from another component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-7, mat-dialog

I have below MatDialog

```
export class ImportProcessingDialog extends AppComponentBase {
    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ImportProcessingDialog>) {
        super(injector);
    }
    onCloseClick(): void{
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

Now I am opening the `MatDialog` from one component as below

```
export class ImportDataComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private importProcesingDialog: MatDialog) {}
    private onClickImport() {
       this.importProcesingDialog.open(ImportProcessingDialog, {
           width: '30%'
       });
    }
}
```

Now I want to close the Dialog from Another component

```
export class RisksComponent {
    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ImportProcessingDialog>) {
    }

    oncloseClick(){
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

When I do this, getting an exception as

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(MainModule)[MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
```

So added the provider as below

```
 providers: [{
            provide: MatDialogRef,
            useValue: {}
          },]
```

With the provider code the error fixed however on I click on `oncloseClick` function getting below error

```
TypeError: this.dialogRef.close is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about storing the dialog ref in a service, which can be accessed from any component!

```
export class ImportProcessingDialog extends AppComponentBase {
    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ImportProcessingDialog>, 
                private testService: TestService) {
        this.testService.dialogRef = dialogRef;
        super(injector);
    }
    onCloseClick(): void{
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

Then on the risks component you can do

```
export class RisksComponent {
    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ImportProcessingDialog>,
                private testService: TestService) {
    }

    oncloseClick(){
        if(this.testService.dialogRef) {
            this.testService.dialogRef.close();
        }
    }
}
```